# CI Can't find session variable when project is accessed from server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, webserver

EDIT: Zen's comment below (which is already the accepted answer) did the trick. I've overwritten the php.ini on the server with the one on my workstation. I no longer have this problem.

On the server: I've tried to print $this->session->userdata('uid') in the controller right after I've set this session, and everything's good during that point but when I var_dump this uid in my login page it returns false. It doesn't exist. I've also already tried erasing cookies and everything in my browser several times. Also tried rebooting.

On my localhost: Everything is working fine.

Has anybody experienced this?

Background: After the system gets the login information entered by the user then validated if the user exists in the database, that's when this session variable is set in the model.

Has anybody experienced this?

My work station is running XAMPP 1.7.7 on windows 7 and the server is using XAMPP for linux on centOS, my browser is chrome. Anything else I should specify please let me know.

Comment: Do you have other `session` data and can you print those ? Maybe you can try this to check if other data available `print_r($this->session->all_userdata())`.

Comment: I've tried this one too. Same thing, the session variable that I'm looking for doesn't exist when the site is accessed from the sever. But, shows up in my localhost. I'm very sure that I uploaded the right file too.

Comment: Make sure you configured it properly, have you setup everything in your `config.php` correctly, did you see other session data.

Comment: I'd like to think so, yes. When I var_dump all_userdata() this is what I get, but I'm looking for 'uid' array(5) {
  ["session_id"]=>
  string(32) "8f25fa3aa6d0905ec3c35f01cda2898b"
  ["ip_address"]=>
  string(12) "192.168.1.59"
  ["user_agent"]=>
  string(99) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
  ["last_activity"]=>
  int(1350479643)
  ["user_data"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Comment: You didn't set it properly, there's a mistake somewhere in your code or `config.php`, check everything, compare the local settings with the server settings.

Comment: I assure you that the file in my server and the one on my local is exactly the same.

Comment: Is your local `php.ini` an exact replica of the one running on your CentOS install? If it's not copy-pasted, try copying the one from CentOS to your local machine and see if it breaks (or vice versa).

Comment: What happens when you `print_r($_SESSION)`?

Comment: @ Tim : My page doesn't recognize $_SESSION, it returns an error that the variable _SESSION is not defined. I will try that @Zen, and get back to you after. Thank you very much.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. I've overwritten php.ini in centOS from windows. It's now working. Hopefully I don't encounter any error regarding this one in the future. Thank you good sir. @Zen, would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: @esandrkwn Please can you post your own solution as an answer so maybe other can benefit from your knowledge

Comment: @Adrian It was Zen's answer that got me through and he had already posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using exactly the same `php.ini` file from your local server on the remote CentOS machine - this will eliminate the possibility of an error in the php configuration (and turns out, that happened...)

This should always be high on your "what is causing this unexplained problem with PHP?" list.

Comment: Glad my horrific times of inconsistent PHP configuration could be of use to you :)